# Maximize violate constraint of non approximated function

Tags: constraint, maximum

here is my code

```
Maximize[{-(10/17) - x + (20 (1 + x))/(17 (2 + x)), 0 <= x <= 1.5}, x]
```

The result I got:
{6.66134*10^-16, {x -> -9.79755*10^-16}}

As you can see, the function is pretty simple, yet Maximize failed to find the maximum of it ( I suspect it is at x= 0) Why is it the case, and what can I do to fix it?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using approximate numbers, when you are actually working with rationals.  Use `3/2` rather `1.5`

```
Maximize[{-(10/17) - x + (20 (1 + x))/(17 (2 + x)), 0 <= x <= 3/2}, x]  
(* {0, {x -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! the problem is that 3/2 is an output I got from another input. Sometimes, it is not something that can be Rationalize at all. So what should I do in those cases? I will put your answer as resolved when I can

Comment: Interesting problem.  I can't see a way to do this.

Comment: `Rationalize[x,0]` will always yield a rational result when `x` is an approximate number.

Comment: It looks like `Maximize[{-(10/17) - x + (20 (1 + x))/(17 (2 + x)), 0 <= x <=r}, x]` for likely any plausible rational `r` greater than zero will find `x==0` as a maximum so it doesn't seem dependent on the exact value or `r`, but only on all the coefficients being exact rationals, likely because an approximate number triggers choosing a different algorithm.

Comment: If I insert a decimal point after any one of those constants it finds an approximate decimal value for the maximum.